# GCP: Producer Portal : Test Deployment during creating Product fails with "One or more licenses are unhealthy."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-license-manager

I am creating a new product in Producer Portal of GCP(Google Cloud Platform) following the steps in [VM Creation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm)

I am using Deployment Manager as the way to deploy the package. On Validate step, the test deployment fails with this error. I havent added virtual-disk-import(projects/compute-image-tools/global/licenses/virtual-disk-import) license as a part of my base image creation. Any idea how this gets added and is there a way to delete this license which gets added automatically during base image creation. We had not faced the same issue when we did the same steps 2 years ago. Is this something that is newly introduced by Google?[License added in the image details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmJWx.png)

```
{   "taskReports": [     {       "taskType": "CHECK_LICENSE_INFO",       "createTime": "2023-09-08T14:25:37.614Z",       "taskExecutionStatus": "ISSUES_FOUND",       "digest": "One or more licenses are unhealthy.",       "errorMessage": "Licenses: projects/compute-image-tools/global/licenses/virtual-disk-import found in the deployment manifest. These licenses are not owned by this Listing and should not be attached to any GCE disks in the deployment"     }   ] }
```

I tried publishing the image and during validation it failed with the above error.